# header fixed and anchor links

Tags: html, css, jscript

I'm using a fixed header for my website and I have a problem: when I use anchor link, the first content go under the header.
When I'm on the page, I can use a script like this:

```
$('.action').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#projects').position().top - 60},800);
});
```

But when I'm on another page, using href="index.html#projects" the problem come out.

There is a solution which allow to use not methods with margin?

Thank you!

Comment: Better if you create a similar [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution for you, but I'll tell you what I would do. Normally when I work with fixed head element, I create a fixed body or content element too.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header" style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;height:50px;">
            <!-- header html here -->
        </div>
        <div id="content" style="position:fixed;top:50px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;">
            <!-- content html here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With a fixed content element I can't scroll down :S

Comment: add the css `overflow:scroll;`

Comment: I think that adding the css 'top: -70px; padding-top: 70px;' is a better solution. Thank you for help!